# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: using with Storyboard and Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have a `UIView` on my Storyboard with four simple constraints set the fill the entire screen - my application is for landscape use only. This `UIView` is to show the camera's live preview, utilizing `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

I have tried using some code examples found on StackOverflow and the wider internet, initiating an `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`; however, none have successfully functioned. The `UIView` on the storyboard always ends up failing to display on screen (white screen when view loads)

I wish to create my app's entire interface with the interface builder using constraints, yet reap the functionality of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. Can someone provide a full code example to assist me if they have a possible solution?

Comment: Why the down vote? Anything I can explain better?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, it works for me. The head file AVCameraCaptureData.h:

```
@interface AVCameraCaptureData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *captureOutput;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

@end

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
{
 #endif /* defined(__cplusplus) */

AVCaptureDevice* getCaptureDeviceByPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition position);
AVCaptureStillImageOutput* getCaptureOutput();
AVCaptureConnection* ConnectionWithMediaType (NSString* mediaType, NSArray* fromConnections);
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* getCapturePreviewLayer(AVCaptureSession* captureSession);
AVCameraCaptureData* CreateCaptureData (AVCaptureDevicePosition position, CGRect presentLayerFrame, NSString* sessionPreset);
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif /* defined(__cplusplus) */
```

AVCameraCaptureData.m file:

```
#import "AVCameraCaptureData.h"
#import "AVCameraUtil.h"

@implementation AVCameraCaptureData

AVCaptureDevice* getCaptureDeviceByPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition position)
{
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
{
    if ([device position] == position)
        return device;
}

return nil;
}

AVCaptureStillImageOutput* getCaptureOutput()
{
AVCaptureStillImageOutput* captureOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

NSDictionary* outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[captureOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

return captureOutput;
}

AVCaptureConnection* ConnectionWithMediaType (NSString* mediaType, NSArray* fromConnections)
{
for (AVCaptureConnection* connection in fromConnections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort* port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:mediaType])
            return connection;
    }
}
return nil;
}

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* getCapturePreviewLayer(AVCaptureSession* captureSession)
{
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession];
//please set frame for yourself
[previewLayer setFrame:[AVCameraUtil screenBoundsFixedToPortraitOrientation]];
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

return previewLayer;
}

AVCameraCaptureData* CreateCaptureData (AVCaptureDevicePosition position, CGRect presentLayerFrame, NSString* sessionPreset)
{
AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

if (sessionPreset == nil)
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
else
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:sessionPreset];

AVCaptureDevice *device = getCaptureDeviceByPosition (position);
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:device error:nil];

if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
    [captureSession addInput:videoDeviceInput];

AVCaptureStillImageOutput* captureOutput = getCaptureOutput();

if ([captureSession canAddOutput:captureOutput])
    [captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];

AVCameraCaptureData *data = [[AVCameraCaptureData alloc] init];
data.captureSession = captureSession;
data.deviceInput = videoDeviceInput;
data.captureOutput = captureOutput;
data.captureConnection = ConnectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, [captureOutput connections]);
data.previewLayer = getCapturePreviewLayer(captureSession);

return data;
}

@end
```

Then you can init AVCameraCaptureData with function in your controller

```
CreateCaptureData(AVCaptureDevicePositionBack, self.view.frame,nil);
```

Start run session:

```
[self.captureData.captureSession startRunning];
```

Add AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to view.layer:

```
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.captureData.previewLayer];
```

Comment: What do I replace `AVCameraUtil` with?

Comment: Additionally, the error `Property 'captureData' not found on object of type 'ViewController'` appears, even after importing the `AVCameraCaptureData`   file

Comment: "captureData" is @property of your ViewController.